# jquery modal form saved to javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a jquery modal form to create a new profile for a database. Basically like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="createModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myDetailsModal" aria-hidden="true">
 <form method="" action="" name="requestprofiledata" id="requestprofiledata">
   <div >
    <label for="comment">Details: </label>     
    <table  id="tableID" class="table table-bordered table-hover tablewithtooltip">
    <thead>
        <tr style="background-color: #787878 ">
        <th>Attribute</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Profile Name</td><td><input type="text" value="Enter a value"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>profileMnemonicEntry</td><td><input type="text" value="Enter a value"/></td></tr>
    </tbody>
   </div>
 </form>
   <div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" name="newProfile" id="newProfile">Save</button>         
   </div>
</div> <!-- /.modal -->
```

I've never used php before, so I set it up to push the data through the url in this "/../../../" form.

This is the javascript I've written so far to push the form data to the server:

```
function createProfile()
{
   var newProfile=new Array();

   $("#newProfile").click(function(){

    newProfile=$("requestprofiledata").serializeArray();


    $.ajax({ URL: '/rest/set/createConfigProfile/newProfile[0]/newProfile[1]/'});

   });
}
```

How can I get the data into the array? Jquery has a lot to offer, but neither .serialize, nor .serializearray have worked with my code. Clearly, .serialize is the wrong function, but I'm not sure which function would be correct. Thank you.

Comment: FYI it's `serializeArray()` - note the capital A

Comment: Thank you, that what what I had originally, but did not work. I must have fat fingered it when submitting here.

Comment: `$("requestprofiledata")` did you mean `$("#requestprofiledata")`?

Answer (score 1):

two slight errors:  http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/107/

```
$("#newProfile").click(function(){        
    var newProfile=$("#requestprofiledata").serializeArray(); // missing # for id selector
    console.log(newProfile);                    
});

<td><input type="text" value="Enter a value" name="profileName"/></td>
<td><input type="text" value="Enter a value" name="Mnemonic"/></td>
```

missing hash tag in selector for ids in jquery, and naming the inputs to your form so they can be mapped by serializeArray().  in the console of the demo, you can look through the objects you have gotten via serializeArray().

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `name` attributes on your form elements.

```
<tr><td>Profile Name</td><td><input type="text" value="Enter a value"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>profileMnemonicEntry</td><td><input type="text" value="Enter a value"/></td></tr>
```

From [.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) documentation

> For a form element's value to be included in the serialized string, the element must have a **name** attribute.

From [.serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

> ...element cannot be disabled and must contain a **name** attribute.

Finally, you have a few errors with your usage for the `.serializeArray()` result

```
var newProfile = $("#requestprofiledata").serializeArray();
var url = "/rest/set/createConfigProfile/" + newProfile[0].value + "/" + newProfile[1].value;
```